# send an array via $http.post in angular to django view

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I want to send this request to a django view:

```
$http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/enterprises/vouchers/_send",
        data: {
            group_id: group_id,
            group_student_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log("emails are sent. please check");
    }).error(function () {
        console.log("failed")
    });
```

In the view I assign them like this:

```
group_student_ids = request.POST['group_student_ids']
group_id = request.POST['group_id']
```

"group_id" is assigned as expected but django is throwing MultiValueDictKeyError for the aray object(group_student_ids)

How do I send an array via a post request?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

First, change your `data` to:

```
data: {
    'group_id': group_id,
    'group_student_ids[]': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

and in your view:

```
group_student_ids = request.POST.getlist('group_student_ids[]')
```

Edit:

Just did some tests in my app; if I print `request.POST`, I'll get

```
<QueryDict: {'group_student_ids[]': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}>
```

And `type(group_student_ids)` would give `<class 'list'>`

Comment: I got this when I printed request.POST: <QueryDict: {u'group_student_ids[][2]': [u'3'], u'group_student_ids[][0]': [u'1'], u'group_id': [u'2'], u'group_student_ids[][1]': [u'2'], u'group_student_ids[][3]': [u'4']}>

Comment: @Rodrigue - Fixed typos; should be able to work now (I used square brackets when calling getlist())

Comment: I don't know why, but it is not working for me. Anyways, I solved this by converting the array into string and splitting it back to the list in the django view. Thank you for your answer)

Comment: @Rodrigue: You're welcome; still not sure why it wouldn't work; perhaps have something to do with the view. Also, I did the test in my app using jQuery's `$.ajax()` instead of AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
group_student_ids = request.POST.getlist('group_student_ids[]')
```

Comment: got an empty list [] :(

Comment: @Rodrigue print `request.POST` in the view, what you get?

Comment: I got this: <QueryDict: {u'group_student_ids[0]': [u'1'], u'group_student_ids[3]': [u'4'], u'group_student_ids[2]': [u'3'], u'group_id': [u'2'], u'group_student_ids[1]': [u'2']}>. So, it turns out that I am getting them but seperately. I don't know why

Comment: @Rodrigue change `group_student_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4]` in ajax call to `"group_student_ids[]": [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: same thing: <QueryDict: {u'group_student_ids[][2]': [u'3'], u'group_student_ids[][0]': [u'1'], u'group_id': [u'2'], u'group_student_ids[][1]': [u'2'], u'group_student_ids[][3]': [u'4']}>

Comment: @Rodrigue are you using any middleware to parse json response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67102/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-rodrigue).